# How to put a javascript link to a list into a html table?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I have created a script for a link to a sharepoint list of information. I am looking to display that in a html page. Wondering how to do this? My javascript code is below.

```js
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Utilities Contract');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
    function(){
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            var itemTitle = oListItem.get_item('Title');

            var itemId = oListItem.get_id();
    },
    function(sender, args){
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To call SharePoint JSOM API, it is necessary to put the script into SharePoint Page instead of normal html page as it needs to use SharePoint ClientContext which is not available in normal html page, you could add the script via ScriptEditor Web Part:
[image]